# How to use XMLSerializer with a Castle ActiveRecord containing an IList<T> member

Tags: .net, xml-serialization, castle-activerecord, generic-list

I am trying to use the XMLSerializer with a castle active record class which looks like the following:

```
[ActiveRecord("Model")]
public class DataModel : ActiveRecordBase
{
    private IList<Document> documents;

    [XmlArray("Documents")]
    public virtual IList<Document> Documents
    {
        get { return documents; }
        set
        {
            documents = value;    
        }
    }
}
```

However, the XMLSerializer runs into trouble because of the IList interface.
(Raises exception: *Cannot serialize member 'DataModel.Documents' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1....*)

I read elsewhere that this is a limitation in the XMLSerializer and the recommended workaround is to declare it as a `List<T>` interface instead.

Therefore I tried changing the `IList<Document>` to `List<Document>`.
This causes ActiveRecord to raise an Exception:
*Type of property DataModel.Documents must be an interface (IList, ISet, IDictionary or their generic counter parts). You cannot use ArrayList or List as the property type.*

So, the question is: How do you use the XMLSerializer with a Castle ActiveRecord containing an IList member?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting... the best I can suggest is to use `[XmlIgnore]` on `Documents` - and does ActiveRecord have a similar way of ignoring a member? You could do something like:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public virtual IList<Document> Documents
{
    get { return documents; }
    set
    {
        documents = value;    
    }
}

[Tell ActiveRecord to ignore this one...]
[XmlArray("Documents"), XmlArrayItem("Document")]
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
public Document[] DocumentsSerialization {
    get {
         if(Documents==null) return null;
         return Documents.ToArray(); // LINQ; or do the long way
    }
    set {
         if(value == null) { Documents = null;}
         else { Documents = new List<Document>(value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. The interface becomes a bit polluted because of the extra property, but I don't really see much of a choice unless Microsoft does something about the IList<T> serialization issue.

Comment: I read that this isn't a bug, but a feature, and the way to get around it is to use data transfer objects (or DTOs).

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft won't implement this](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=105767), so you have to work around it. One way would be to use the non-generic `IList`:

```
[ActiveRecord("Model")]
public class DataModel : ActiveRecordBase<DataModel> {
    [XmlArray("Documents")]
    [HasMany(typeof(Document)]
    public virtual IList Documents {get;set;}
}
```

[Here](http://srtsolutions.com/blogs/billwagner/archive/2006/11/20/xml-serialization-and-generic-interfaces.aspx)'s some more information about this bug.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the Microsoft bug report. It really sucks that they aren't fixing this. I don't want to lose the type-safety benefit of using the generic list though, so I'll have to either go for the solution suggested by Marc above, or else shift everything to the DataContractSerializer.