# XML serialization problem in C# ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

i keep getting this error:

> Exception Details:
>   System.NotSupportedException: Cannot
>   serialize member
>   HannaPrintsDataAccess.Customer.CustomerAddresses
>   of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[HannaPrintsDataAccess.CustomerAddress,
>   HannaPrintsDataAccess,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an
>   interface.
>
> **Here is the stack trace:** [NotSupportedException: Cannot
>   serialize member
>   HannaPrintsDataAccess.Customer.CustomerAddresses
>   of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[HannaPrintsDataAccess.CustomerAddress,
>   HannaPrintsDataAccess,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an
>   interface.]
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Cannot
>   serialize member
>   'HannaPrintsDataAccess.Customer.CustomerAddresses'
>   of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[HannaPrintsDataAccess.CustomerAddress,
>   HannaPrintsDataAccess,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]]', see inner
>   exception for more details.]
>   System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.CheckSupportedMember(TypeDesc
>   typeDesc, MemberInfo member, Type
>   type) +889917
>   System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.GetPropertyModel(PropertyInfo
>   propertyInfo) +132
>   System.Xml.Serialization.StructModel.GetFieldModel(MemberInfo
>   memberInfo) +129
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping
>   mapping, StructModel model, Boolean
>   openModel, String typeName,
>   RecursionLimiter limiter) +1226
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel
>   model, String ns, Boolean openModel,
>   XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter
>   limiter) +460
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel
>   model, String ns, ImportContext
>   context, String dataType,
>   XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats,
>   Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter
>   limiter) +1415
>
> [InvalidOperationException: There was
>   an error reflecting type
>   'HannaPrintsDataAccess.Customer'.]
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel
>   model, String ns, ImportContext
>   context, String dataType,
>   XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats,
>   Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter
>   limiter) +1621
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportAccessorMapping(MemberMapping
>   accessor, FieldModel model,
>   XmlAttributes a, String ns, Type
>   choiceIdentifierType, Boolean rpc,
>   Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter
>   limiter) +10296
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportFieldMapping(StructModel
>   parent, FieldModel model,
>   XmlAttributes a, String ns,
>   RecursionLimiter limiter) +139
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping
>   mapping, StructModel model, Boolean
>   openModel, String typeName,
>   RecursionLimiter limiter) +1273
>
> [InvalidOperationException: There was
>   an error reflecting property
>   'Customer'.]
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping
>   mapping, StructModel model, Boolean
>   openModel, String typeName,
>   RecursionLimiter limiter) +2167
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportStructLikeMapping(StructModel
>   model, String ns, Boolean openModel,
>   XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter
>   limiter) +460
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel
>   model, String ns, ImportContext
>   context, String dataType,
>   XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats,
>   Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter
>   limiter) +1415
>
> [InvalidOperationException: There was
>   an error reflecting type
>   'HannaPrintsDataAccess.CustomerAddress'.]
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel
>   model, String ns, ImportContext
>   context, String dataType,
>   XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats,
>   Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter
>   limiter) +1621
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.CreateArrayElementsFromAttributes(ArrayMapping
>   arrayMapping, XmlArrayItemAttributes
>   attributes, Type arrayElementType,
>   String arrayElementNs,
>   RecursionLimiter limiter) +227
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportArrayLikeMapping(ArrayModel
>   model, String ns, RecursionLimiter
>   limiter) +207
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel
>   model, String ns, ImportContext
>   context, String dataType,
>   XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats,
>   Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter
>   limiter) +1143
>
> [InvalidOperationException: There was
>   an error reflecting type
>   'HannaPrintsDataAccess.CustomerAddress[]'.]
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel
>   model, String ns, ImportContext
>   context, String dataType,
>   XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats,
>   Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter
>   limiter) +1621
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel
>   model, String ns, ImportContext
>   context, String dataType,
>   XmlAttributes a, RecursionLimiter
>   limiter) +28
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportElement(TypeModel
>   model, XmlRootAttribute root, String
>   defaultNamespace, RecursionLimiter
>   limiter) +125
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(Type
>   type, XmlRootAttribute root, String
>   defaultNamespace) +97
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type
>   type, String defaultNamespace) +461
>   System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type
>   type) +6
>   HannaPrintsBusiness.Services.Live.CustomerService.GetCustomerAddressesXml(CustomerAddress[]
>   customerAddresses) in
>   E:\ProjectsOld\HannaPrints\HannaPrintsBusiness\Services\Live\CustomerService.cs:148
>   CreateGreetingCard.orderButton_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\HostingSpaces\greetwus\galadavetiye.com\wwwroot\HannaPrints\HannaPrints\WebUI\CreateGreetingCard.aspx.cs:198
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e) +111
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +110
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   +13    System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection
>   postData) +36
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1565

I cant seem to figure this out, I am pretty sure its just some configuration that needs to be changed because before we got this code, supposedly it was working correctly, but we cant figure out why we are getting this error.  If anyone could help that would be great.  Thanks!!!

***UPDATE*** 
I tried changing the IList to List, but it does not do anything.  Here is my classes with the customer address:

CUSTOMER CLASS:::

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using Castle.ActiveRecord;

namespace HannaPrintsDataAccess
{
    public partial class Customer
    {
        private IList _customerAddresses;

```
    public CustomerAddress GetPrimaryCustomerAddress()
    {
        foreach (CustomerAddress address in _customerAddresses)
        {
            if (address.IsPrimary)
                return address;
        }
        return null;
    }


    [HasMany(typeof(CustomerAddress), ColumnKey = "CustomerId", Table = "Customer")]
    public virtual IList<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses
    {
        get
        {
            return this._customerAddresses;
        }
        set
        {
            this._customerAddresses = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Here is the Customer Address class::::

```
using System.IO;
```

using System.Xml.Serialization;
using Castle.ActiveRecord;

namespace HannaPrintsDataAccess
{
    public partial class CustomerAddress
    {
        public string ToXml()
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(GetType());
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            serializer.Serialize(memoryStream, this);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return new StreamReader(memoryStream).ReadToEnd();
        }

```
    [BelongsTo("CustomerId")]
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

}

Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message explicitly tells you the `XmlSerializer` cannot serialize interfaces.

You probably had:

```
public List<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses  { get; set; }
```

which you changed to:

```
public IList<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses  { get; set; }
```

which no longer works.

Comment: Hey i tried this and it did not work, Ive updated my question with the code from both classes

Answer (score 1):

You can put

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(Type = typeof(List<HannaPrintsDataAccess.CustomerAddress>) )]
```

on the property

```
HannaPrintsDataAccess
```

Assuming that the member is in fact an instance of `List<T>`

Basically, this attribute is required to support inheritance with Xml serialization. That is, if a property is of type IList and the instance is of type `List<T>` (which inherits from IList), you will need to add that attribute to the property specifying `List<T>.`

Comment: You cannot decorate a property with the `XmlInclude` attribute.

Comment: Can you please explain why not?

Comment: "It is important to note here that relying on inheritance is not sufficient. Developers must declare derived types to the XmlSerializer, either by attaching XmlInclude attributes to the base class or by attaching XmlElement attributes to the fields that can hold objects of types derived from the declared type." @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302290.aspx

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution but it did not work, I made an edit in my question with more info

Comment: The problem is with the property CustomerAddress on class Customer. What is the actual instance type of CustomerAddress on Customer? That is, if you stop at a breakpoint and type myCustomer.CustomerAddress.GetType().FullName, what prints out? It's this type that you need to put in the attribute on the CustomerAddress property.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753099/how-to-use-xmlserializer-with-a-castle-activerecord-containing-an-ilistt-member

Answer (score 1):

The interface property is still `public`, so the serializer will still attempt to serialize it (and crash).

Put an `XmlIgnore` attribute on the interface property like this:

```
[XmlIgnore]
[HasMany(typeof(CustomerAddress), ColumnKey = "CustomerId", Table = "Customer")]
public virtual IList<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses
{
    get
    {
        return this._customerAddresses;
    }
    set
    {
        this._customerAddresses = value;
    }
}
```

You `List` implementation is screwed up also.  Add this declaration right below your `IList<CustomerAddress>` property declaration:

```
public List<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses
{
    get
    {
        return (List<CustomerAddress>)this._customerAddresses;
    }
    set
    {
        this._customerAddresses = value;
    }
}
```

HTH...

P.S. For future reference, remember that all public properties are visible to the xml serializer, and it **will** try to serialize them.  Make sure to put `XmlIgnore` attributes on the properties that should not be serialized.

Comment: Hey, i tried this and it still gives me the SAME exact error, I don't understand why, because I double checked my remote files to make sure the changes went through, but it still has the same error message, even if i change it to List instead of IList.

Answer (score 0):

The error message seems pretty clear to me:

> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize member HannaPrintsDataAccess.Customer.CustomerAddresses of type System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[[HannaPrintsDataAccess.CustomerAddress, HannaPrintsDataAccess, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] because it is an interface.

Try replacing the type of `HannaPrintsDataAccess.Customer.CustomerAddresses`, which is currently `IList<CustomerAddress>`, with the concrete type (e.g. `List<CustomerAddress>`) instead of the interface.

Comment: Hi, I tried this solution but it did not work, I made an edit in my question with more info

Answer (score 0):

I had such exception with $.ajax request,  `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` fixed my problem.